# How can I create a single variable and add new rows within the column with new rnorm values?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, concatenation

I want to create a variable with 200 rows under 1 column and values generated from `rnorm`. Every 50 rows, I would like to change the mean of the values. I keep getting 4 rows of 50 columns or 4 columns of 50 rows, but cannot seem to create 1 column with 200 rows. Help appreciated.

I tried `rbind` and `cbind` but I'm missing something

```
Anx_T1 = rnorm(50, 3, 1) %>%
 rbind((rnorm(50,11,1))) %>%
  rbind((rnorm(50,3,1))) %>%
   rbind((rnorm(50,11,1)))
```

Hoping to get something like:

```
.  Anx_T1
1     3
2     4
3     3
4     2
5     3
...
199   4
200   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
data.frame(var = c(rnorm(50, 3, 1),
                   rnorm(50,11,1),
                   rnorm(50,3,1),
                   rnorm(50,11,1)))
```

Comment: Yes, I was overthinking this! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need `c` and not `rbind`:

If you want your result in one column of a data.frame you can use:

```
data.frame(Anx_T1 = c(rnorm(50, 3, 1), rnorm(50, 11, 1), rnorm(50, 3, 1)))
```